# various phone states differentiation

Tags: java, android, phone-call

How can I differentiate between incoming and outgoing calls ?.
for both cases, the mobile is in an off-hook state, but for the incoming call it is in the ringing state then goes to the off-hook one,

I tried this code but it's not working effectively, as a ringing variable is always false.
and there is another question how can I get the outgoing call number .. thanks in advance

```
public class states extends BroadcastReceiver {
boolean Ringing = false;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
 Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Ringing = true ;
 }
    else if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        if (Ringing) {
            // do nothing
        }else{
           // do something
}
 else if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        Ringing = false ;
    }
}
}
```

these are my permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


  <receiver android:name=".states">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: For your question ougoing call number, that means you are willing to get your own contact number. isn't it?

Comment: No, I mean the number I'm calling ..

Comment: i just edited the answer and plzz check the TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still in the same problem .. can you plz check my permissions i added them in the question , it may be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For differentiation of incoming and outgoing Calls you can use a broadcast Receiver for this :
add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />` in your receiver and process it in your onReceive() method.

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter >             
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />             
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

For getting the outgoing number

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if(state==null)
    {
        //Outgoing call
        String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.i("tag","Outgoing number : "+number);
    }
    else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
    {
        //Incoming call
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Log.i("tag","Incoming number : "+number);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but there is no "null" state , it's either off hook or idle .. even after i changed the state to be             if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK) || state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) )  I didint get the outgoing number ..

Comment: It worked ... I added this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>   and it got the null state , and the outgoing number ... thanks for your help